# Writing text in MS Word

Tags: text, ms-word

I am developing an application that exports a number of editText in an MS Word file (.doc) with text formatting (font, textSize, underlined text, bold, breaking line etc) so I am asking if there is a library doing that or a code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure there is, it depends on which text editor you use. If you use Dreamweaver, you can simply paste it in the liveview (try it, it's worth it, download the demo) but I assume you dont have it so, simply use this [website here.](http://document.online-convert.com/convert-to-html)

Give me a tick if you're happy with my answer :)

Comment: Think's for your answer but i didn't understant the goal of (text editor i use), i just want to export and editText to a word document instead of a txt file a formating it (the text) programatically.